# Regarding a bounded linear functional non zero on the scalars

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional complex Banach algebra with unity. I wanted to know if there exists a bounded linear functional on $X$ which is non-zero only on the scalar multiples of the unit element in $X$.

Comment: @Mark Hi. Sorry. I have corrected it to Banach algebra with unity.

Comment: Well, no. Suppose we call the identity $e$. Let $x$ be any element which is not a scalar multiple of $e$. Then $e+x$ and $-x$ are two elements which are not scalar multiples of $e$. Since they both belong to the kernel of your functional, then so is their sum, which is $e$. That's a contradiction.